# Expand.grid with unknown number of columns

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
map_value   LDGroup    ComboNum  
1              1           1  
1              1           2  
1              1           3  
1              2           1  
1              2           2  
1              3           1  
1              3           2
```

I want to find all combinations, selecting one from each LD group.  Expand.grid seems to work for this, doing

```
expand.grid(df[df$LDGroup==1,3],df[df$LDGroup==2,3],df[df$LDGroup==3,3])
```

My problem is that I have about 500 map_values I need to do this for and I do not know what number of `LDGroups` will exist for each `map_value`.  Is there a way to dynamically provide the function arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split the 3rd column by the 'LDGroup' and apply the `expand.grid`

```
out <- expand.grid(split(df$ComboNum, df$LDGroup))
names(out) <- paste0("Var", names(out))
```

Comment: That worked, thanks.  I already see a few other places that split command will be useful.